# Why is select features button not working in ArcGIS 10.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, select, table-of-contents

Every time i opened a mxd file (in ArcGis 10.3) the default of most of the layersis in "Not Selectable". I search a way to change the default in the table of content ,so all the layers will be always in "selectable" default like the layer "gvul":

[image]

I try to change it in selection options and make sure that interactive selection method is "create a new selection" but i didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To easily select all layers to be selectable, you need to add a button from your toolbox.

> Click the Customize menu > Customize Mode > Commands tab. Type “set
>   selectable layers” in the “show commands containing” search box, and
>   drag and drop the Set Selectable Layers command on to your Selection
>   menu.

Once you have all of the layers selected as you like, save your .mxd and the next time you open, you will have all layers selectable by default.

Note that if you have a default document (mxd) set up by your organization, your changes may be overridden, so do a Save As to change the name/location of your customized mxd.